# httphandler not working in IE

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler

i have written a httphandler and i have registered in web.config in iis7 (pipeline integrated):

```
<system.webServer>
 <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
<add verb="*" name="MediaHandler" path="*.pdf" type="Namespace.Classe, Assembly" resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

The httphandler restricts access to pdf files but now i'm trying with "response.write("foo")".
IT doesn't work only in Internet Explorer

Second request: Can i get it using a classic pipeline?

Comment: Can you post the essence of what your HttpHandler is doing in a code snippet?

Comment: public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Write("foo");
}

Comment: you may try to put a `<remove verb="*" path="*.pdf"/>` before your <add element

Comment: Not possible with httphandler. I have only remove name="" and i can't remove StaticFile